# Average data in its own row

Tags: sql-server

I have data that returns the same value multiple times in one column, I only want to include the first value or even average the group, since they are all the same value. The group itself might have 3 rows of payments, but the payments are the same. I just want the three rows to show, but only the one payment in its own column.

In the data below I would like to add another column that averages Rich and Bob's value and inputs the amount in the top row for Rich and Bob.

Sample Data:

```
1  Rich  300
2  Rich  300
3  Rich  300
4  Bob   250
5  Bob   250
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide sample date and expected output. And **please** make use of the formatting possibilities here on Stack Overflow!

Comment: One more point to state: If I understand you correctly this is rather a job for your application than for the database... And: please state the version of your SQL Server...

Comment: Since you're adding a whole new column, what would you expect the value to be for rows 2, 3, and 5?

Comment: i would expect the value for Rich to be 300, the value for Bob to be 250.  To put another way I would like to average Rich and Bob's values in their own row and still keep the values of all their numbers in the current column

Comment: i would expect the value in row 1 to be 300,

Comment: 2 and 3 to be null, 4 to be 250 and 5 to be null

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

Just paste this into an empty query window and exectue. Adapt to your needs...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT, PersonName VARCHAR(100),Amount DECIMAL(6,2))
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'Rich',300)
,(2,'Rich',300)
,(3,'Rich',300)
,(4,'Bob',250)
,(5,'Bob',250);

WITH NumberedPerson AS
(
    SELECT tbl.*
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PersonName ORDER BY ID) PersonID
          ,AVG(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY PersonName) PersonAvg
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
)
SELECT *
     ,CASE WHEN PersonID=1 THEN PersonAvg ELSE NULL END AS AverageInFirstRow
FROM NumberedPerson
ORDER BY ID
```

But - to be honest - that is absolutely not the way how this should be done...

Comment: @DominickLaDuca, Did you try this? Did it work? If yes please vote up and mark as accepted, thx!